# Find the max volume using polynomials with the sum of the height and perimeter less than 100cm

Tags: functions, polynomials, optimization, volume

I have to find out which shape of packaging for a fragile object has the most volume to fit the object and styrofoam packing. The sum of the height and the perimeter must be less than $100cm$.

There is a circular base (cylindrical package), a square base (rectangular package) and a rectangle base ($w = 2l$)(rectangular package).

The problem is I have no idea how to start. will the function represent the volume? the base? the height and perimeter? can I assume the y-axis is the volume?

Another question is: what is the perimeter of a cylinder? some one said (not on this site) that it was $2{\pi}r+2h$ but wouldn't it be $4{\pi}r+2h$ because there are two circumferences in a cylinder.

EDIT: this probably is a cubic function that is representing the volume

Comment: Do you mean surface area?

Comment: no, the page specified that the perimeter plus the hight must be less than 100 cm. Surface area is not mentioned at all

Comment: So the perimeter of the base? Or all of the faces?

Comment: Please proofread your question. A base doesn't have a volume. You mean to say "which base should I choose so that the volume is maximum."

Comment: I have no idea...

Comment: the page only says "The shipping company allows you to send any shape of package, as long as the sum of the height and perimeter are less than 100 centimetres."

Comment: do you think they mean the height is less than 100 and the perimeter is less than 100? it says the sum, though, so it would be p + h = 100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no maximum volume, since the problem specifies that the sum must be **less than** $100$. So we assume that the regulations say $\le 100$.

To maximize volume, it is best to use the full $100$. For height $h$ and radius $r$, we have the constraint $h+2\pi r=100$. This is because the perimeter of the *base* is $2\pi r$.

The volume is $\pi r^2 h$. So we want to maximize $\pi r^2(100-2\pi r)$, where $0\le r\le \frac{100}{2\pi}$. To solve this problem, we can use the usual tools (derivative).

If we solve the problem of the previous paragraph, then whatever maximum volume $V$ we get, we can get arbitrarily close to $V$ if we take the *less than* seriously, but we cannot reach $V$.

The square base and rectangular base problems are handled in a similar way.

Comment: I think I've got it :)